# Connect to wifi network in android, return if incorrect password

Tags: android, wifi

I would like to make an application that will let the user connect to a wifi network, however I am having trouble getting a connection to a network

My current code is:

```
    WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
    wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
    WifiConfiguration wc = new WifiConfiguration();
    wifi.startScan();
    List<ScanResult> l=wifi.getScanResults();
    wc.SSID = l.get(NUMBER).SSID;
    post(wc.SSID);
    /*This is the bit that I think is failing, my network does not have these properties.. but I can't see how to get them from the Scan Result*/
    wc.preSharedKey  = "\"passw0rd123\"";
    wc.hiddenSSID = false;
    wc.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;        
    wc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
    wc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
    wc.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
    wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
    wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
    wc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
    int res = wifi.addNetwork(wc);
    post("add Network returned " + res);
    boolean b = wifi.enableNetwork(res, true);        
    post("enableNetwork returned " + b);
```

I think this has to do with the settings (after my comment) that are not the same as my networks configuration, but I don't know how to get these settings from the ScanResult..

I would also like to know if the it has connected properly.

Comment: hey man, did you reach something in that issue?

Answer (score -1):

make sure you set the correct permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: I have access_wifi_state, change_wifi_state and access_network_state

Answer (score -1):

Check whether WIFI is enabled or not in ur device and remeber in emulator u cant check it

If WIFI is disabled in onclick of the alert u can show the Wifi- settings page like this

```
 WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

           if ((wifi.isWifiEnabled() == true)) {

      Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"MOBILE Is Connected TO WI-FI!",
              }

              else {

                AlertDialog.Builder WIFIOFF = new Builder(MyTestglobe.this);
                WIFIOFF.setCancelable(false);
                WIFIOFF.setTitle("Connection Error");
                WIFIOFF.setMessage(" Please Enable Your WIFI/INTERNET !");
                WIFIOFF.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
             startActivity(new Intent( Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));

                            }
                        });
                WIFIOFF.show();

            }
```

And give these permisions in ur Manifest.xml

```
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />    
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: I do a wifimanager.setWifiEnabled(true); I don't think wifi not being on is the problem (it always is!)

Comment: so whats ur question then? edit ur question and come with exact requirement. How could u expect a correct answer for incorrect question!